# Add query string as route value dictionary to ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an ActionLink to export data from a grid. The grid is filtered by values from the query string. Here's an example of the url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/GridPage?Column=Name&Direction=Ascending&searchName=text
```

Here's the code to add my ActionLink to the page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel",    // link text
    "Export",                          // action name
    "GridPage",                        // controller name
    Request.QueryString.ToRouteDic(),  // route values
    new { @class = "export"})          // html attributes
```

When the link is displayed, the url is this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/GridPage/Export?Count=3&Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The reason that your attempt doesn't work is that .ToString() is not overloaded on the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> class (and it shouldn't be, since that is used to store a lot more than just route dictionary arguments).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

I'm not sure this is the cleanest or most correct way but it does work

I didn't use your extension method. You'll have to reintegrate that:

```
@{ 
    RouteValueDictionary tRVD = new RouteValueDictionary(ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
    foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys ) 
    { 
        tRVD[key]=Request.QueryString[key].ToString();
    }
}
```

then

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel",    // link text
"Export",                          // action name
"GridPage",                      // controller name
tRVD, 
new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "export" } }) // html attributes
```

Results in

[image: Results]

with class export[image]

Comment: I think this will transform a query string like a=1&a=2 into a=1,2

Comment: QueryString.GetValues gets around this problem (it returns an array of strings), but I don't yet know how to add it to the RouteValueDictionary

Comment: Hey @zod, did you ever find out how to add them to the RouteValueDictionary? I can't find a way.

Comment: @zod unfortunately it's a Dictionary, so they have to be unique entries

Comment: Does not work for me. Despite I use RouteValueDictionary in that argument, the object itself is serialized to the Query string, not my desired key-value pairs.

Answer (score 8):

If you look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx

```
//You are currently using:
ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)
//You want to be using:
ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary<String, Object>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross-posting from [How do I get the QueryString values into a the RouteValueDictionary using Html.BeginForm()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675616/how-do-i-get-the-querystring-values-into-a-the-routevaluedictionary-using-html-b/26533087#26533087)

Here's a helper extension so you can dump the querystring in any method accepting a `RouteValueDictionary`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Turn the current request's querystring into the appropriate param for <code>Html.BeginForm</code> or <code>Html.ActionLink</code>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="html"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <remarks>
/// See discussions:
/// * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675616/how-do-i-get-the-querystring-values-into-a-the-routevaluedictionary-using-html-b
/// * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165700/add-query-string-as-route-value-dictionary-to-actionlink
/// </remarks>
public static RouteValueDictionary QueryStringAsRouteValueDictionary(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    // shorthand
    var qs = html.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

    // because LINQ is the (old) new black
    return qs.AllKeys.Aggregate(new RouteValueDictionary(html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values),
        (rvd, k) => {
            // can't separately add multiple values `?foo=1&foo=2` to dictionary, they'll be combined as `foo=1,2`
            //qs.GetValues(k).ForEach(v => rvd.Add(k, v));
            rvd.Add(k, qs[k]);
            return rvd;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `CopyTo` from `System.Collections.Specialized` like this:

```
var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Request.QueryString.CopyTo(queryParams);
var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(queryParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version that also handles the case where the same key appears several times:

```
public static RouteValueDictionary QueryStringToRouteValueDictionary(this HtmlHelper html)
{
   var qs = html.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

   return qs.AllKeys.Aggregate(new RouteValueDictionary(html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values),
    (rvd, k) =>
   {
     // get values
     var values = qs.GetValues(k);
     // if only one value simply add it
     if (values.Length == 1)
     {
       rvd.Add(k, values[0]);
     }
     else
     {
       // an array has to be add using the syntax <k>[<i>] for the key values, where k is the key itself and i is the counter
       for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
       {
         rvd.Add($"{k}[{i}]", values[i]);
       }
     }
     return rvd;
  });
}
```