# How to put QueryString back into ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

My action links are generated from code below:

```
@{
    var routeValues = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
    var queryString = this.Request.QueryString;
    var controller = routeValues["controller"] as string;
    var action = routeValues["action"] as string;
}
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>@Resources.Global.Language : </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("English", @action, @controller, new { culture = "en" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "en" })
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("中文", @action, @controller, new { culture = "zh" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "zh" })
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I put the `queryString` back into those ActionLink?
My `queryString` will be dynamic with one or more parameters

Comment: You can get all request parameters as Request.param["nameOfParamter"] for all expected cases. if it does not work you can share your url and desired output for more help.

Comment: Not related, but your do not need your `@action` and `@controller` - you can just use `@Html.ActionLink("English", null, null, new { ..`

Comment: @AayQue `this.Request.QueryString` will return all parameters and values for me, why would I want to use request.param["nameOfParamter"] ?

Comment: @Pop I think you will have to write manual code as I discussed. I don't think there will be an automated way.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't think of your query string as of a string. It has been parsed and put into `Request.QueryString`. You need to simply pass that dictionary to `ActionLink`. The only additional step is adding a different key per link and making sure the [correct overload of `ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504988(v=vs.108).aspx) is used:

```
@functions
{
    RouteValueDictionary MergeIn(IDictionary<string, object> original_data, object more_data)
    {
        var result = new RouteValueDictionary(original_data);
        foreach (var k in HtmlHelper.ObjectToDictionary(more_data)) 
        {
            result[k.Key] = k.Value;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

@{
    var query_values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    this.Request.QueryString.CopyTo(query_values);
}
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("English", null, MergeIn(query_values, new { culture = "en" }), HtmlHelper.ObjectToDictionary(new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "en" }))
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("中文", null, MergeIn(query_values, new { culture = "zh" }), HtmlHelper.ObjectToDictionary( new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "zh" }))
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have this error `HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for ObjectToDictionary`, is it because I am using .Net Framework 4?

Comment: @Pop No, [it's part of the MVC framework](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs). Are you using version 5?

Comment: Think not. `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: @Pop Your options are to upgrade to 5.2.3, to take the [source code of `ObjectToDictionary`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Utils/TypeHelper.cs) (which depends on `PropertyHelper`), or to use other techniques from the duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

I Found a solution in another question on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26533136/2424987

In this solution drzaus creates a new RouteValueDictionary from the querystring.
You can then put the new parameters you want into the dictionary and pass that to the actionlink method.

this is the code drzaus proposes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Turn the current request's querystring into the appropriate param for     <code>Html.BeginForm</code> or <code>Html.ActionLink</code>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="html"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <remarks>
/// See discussions:
/// * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675616/how-do-i-get-the-querystring-values-into-a-the-routevaluedictionary-using-html-b
/// * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165700/add-query-string-as-route-value-dictionary-to-actionlink
/// </remarks>
public static RouteValueDictionary QueryStringAsRouteValueDictionary(this HtmlHelper html)
{
// shorthand
var qs = html.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

// because LINQ is the (old) new black
return qs.AllKeys.Aggregate(new RouteValueDictionary(html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values),
    (rvd, k) => {
        // can't separately add multiple values `?foo=1&foo=2` to dictionary, they'll be combined as `foo=1,2`
        //qs.GetValues(k).ForEach(v => rvd.Add(k, v));
        rvd.Add(k, qs[k]);
        return rvd;
    });
}
```